# Tomee startup error with Kundera

Tags: jakarta-ee, cassandra, apache-tomee, kundera

I am trying to use Kundera with Tomee. After giving Kundera dependency I am getting below error.

```
Nov 11, 2016 12:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tomee-start-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1537)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1518)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:762)
```

I have give below dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
   <version>3.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: this information is insufficient to debug the issue. Share more details of the project. Is there ant Kundera related errors in the log?

Comment: Service was working fine until this Kundera dependency added. Should I exclude JPA related dependency ? There is no Kundera related error in the log

Comment: More information is needed to debug this. I may need sample project. I am from team Kundera. We can discuss this issue at [Kundera chat](https://gitter.im/impetus-opensource/Kundera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

```
Nov 11, 2016 12:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy:
```

You have the actual exception giving you why it failed.

I suspect you have some library conflicts due to kundera transitive dependencies (take care it is very huge and you need to exclude a bunch of them when not in plain SE standalone mode, at least javax APIs).